# Runtime.getRuntime().exec with Phantomjs not working

Tags: java, ubuntu, highcharts, phantomjs, runtime.exec

I am trying to save a highcharts PNG file in the server. I am using ubuntu, phantomjs, highcharts, highcharts exporting, jquery.

If I run this in terminal, it's working:

```
phantomjs /home/save-piechart.js '[{"name":"Category A","y":13},{"name":"Category B","y":8},{"name":"Category C","y":5},{"name":"Category D","y":4},{"name":"Category E","y":2},{"name":"Category F","y":2},{"name":"Category G","y":1},{"name":"Category H","y":1}]' 'trial.png'
```

If I run the code in eclipse, it's working as well. However, it doesn't work after I deploy it.

The save-piechart.js I am calling from my java code is:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

//load JS libraries
page.injectJs("jquery.min.js");
page.injectJs("highcharts.js");
page.injectJs("exporting.js");

//image properties
var image_path = '/home/report/chart-images/';
var raw_json = system.args[1];
var json = raw_json.replace(/_~/g, " ");
json = JSON.parse(json)
var image_filename = system.args[2];

//chart properties
var chart_args = {
width: 800,
height: 400,
jsondata: json
};

var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt){
$('body').prepend('<div id="container"></div>');

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        width: opt.width,
        height: opt.height,
    type : 'pie'
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type : 'category',
    crosshair : true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min : 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            enableMouseTracking: false, 
            shadow: false, 
            animation: false
        }
    },
colors:[
    '#C53B38',
    '#9ABF49',
    '#513F66',
    '#35ADCD',
    '#346DB0',
    '#396C31',
    '#F2D16D',
    '#706B40',
    '#465B48',
    '#6B7179',
    '#26C2B6',
    '#546164',
    '#FD7975',
    '#F3D032',
    '#768082',
    '#BF8F8F',
    '#594673',
    '#6595BF',
    '#9ABBD9',
    '#B1A1C0',
    '#E8DFC8',
    '#2D5261',
    '#8D9184',
    '#345E7C',
    '#0F7169',
    '#C93823',
    '#E9A423',
    '#89B147',
    '#A74C1D',
    '#FDE778',
    '#BCCED9',
    '#4D8A1C',
    '#F49443',
    '#818D8E',
    '#A64941',
    '#00BEE8',
    '#5F3F1A',
    '#E6F7D2',
    '#95DCE8',
    '#FFFFFF'
    ],
credits : {
    enabled : false
},
    series: [{
        data: opt.jsondata
    }]
});

return chart.getSVG();
},  chart_args);

//save diagram as PNG
page.render(image_path + image_filename);

phantom.exit();
```

My java code is:

```
String json_data = raw_json.replaceAll(" ", "_~");
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("phantomjs /home/save-piechart.js " + json_data + " " + image_filename);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
        int read = 0;
        byte[] output = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = bis.read(output)) != -1) {
            logger.info("Running save-piechart: " + output[read]);
        }
        bis.close();
```

I deploy my code using these steps:

- Maven -> Update Project
- mvn package
- sudo service tomcat7 stop
- rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*
- (copy ROOT.war to downloads dir)
- sudo cp /home/Downloads/ROOT.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
- sudo service tomcat7 start
- (copy C:\lib to downloads dir)
- sudo cp /home/Downloads/lib/* /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
- sudo service tomcat7 restart

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work after I deploy it"? Are you sure that **phantomjs** is found when executing outside of your IDE? i.e. are you sure your "current directory" is the same/good?

Comment: @Bsquare I mean the image is not being created after I deploy the project. I'm not sure if phantomjs is found outside my IDE. I installed it though using "apt install phantomjs" -- that's why it's working on my IDE and terminal. In addition, I am using absolute paths in my code. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: I guess you should have an exception if something goes wrong; can you check the log, and copy/paste it?

Comment: @Bsquare no exception. same info logs produced in debug and prod. But in debug, the images are actually being creading.

Comment: @Bsquare any ideas? :/

Comment: Did you try with a breakpoint on the **Process process** line (only possible in Debug, where it is already working, true)? At least to have an idea where is the **current directory** when executing?  DId you check your Debug/Release launcher configuration?